# saving answers in an online test and sending them to database

Tags: mysql, arrays, testing, insert

I'm asked to write an online test. I have 2 tables, one includes questions (2 fields, one for id and one for question text). And another table for saving answers (with 3 fields, one for id, one for question id and one for the answer).

Here's how I've written it so far:

```
<form name="test" method="post" action="index.html">
    <div class="slideshowContainer">
         $question_query=dbquery("SELECT * FROM questions");
         while($question_array=dbarray($question_query)){
            echo'
            <div class="question">
               '.$question_array['question_text'].'
               <br />
               <textarea name="'.$question_array['id'].'"></textarea>
            </div>
            ';
         }
          echo'
          <input id="finish" type="submit" name="finish_test" value="send" />
    </div>
</form>';
```

I'm also using cycle plugin so users can see the questions as slides and write the answers in each textarea provided for each specific question.

What I can't do is the way I should write the if(isset($_POST['finish_test'])) part. Because as I know in this way, the received data is in the form of an array. So I thought I might need another for or while element when I'm gonna save the answers and send them to my database.

What can you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you are gonna need to loop through the results of the $_POST but its nice to make different id for each of the text areas in your code. That way you can identify which are which answers. So to do that I would do something like this.

```
  while($question_array=dbarray($question_query)){
        i = 0;        
        echo'
        <div class="question".i>
           '.$question_array['question_text'].'
           <br />
           <input id='question' type='hidden' value="'.$question_array['id'].'"/> 
           <textarea name="answer".i></textarea>
        </div>'; 
         i++;
     }
```

Now since I know that i starts with 0 and ends when the questions end I can loop through that and access $_POST['answer'.i] and make the insertion.

```
while ($_POST['answer'.$i]) {
      $i = 0;    
  //insert query after establishing connection, which i believe you got figured out 
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO ANSWERS VALUES ($_POST['answer'.$i],        $_POST['question'.$i])';//Note you must have the question id in some hidden input field
      $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );//where $conn is your connection object
    //after this you might want to do something with the $result, 
     $i++;
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer. And may I ask how I should write the insert query as well ? The ANSWERS table has the following fields: id, question_id, answer_text.

Comment: Yes that's already figured out, and thanks a lot again for helping me out. Thumbs up ;)

Comment: @ArashBarazandeh i'm glad that I could be any help but you can actually do Thumbs up by voting my answer and if you find the answer correct you can accept it. Thnx!